# issue on creating language model for sinhala usin SRILM

Tags: voice-recognition, pocketsphinx, srilm

I'm trying to create a sinhala voice recognition system using pocketsphinx. I use SRILM tool to create language model. My source files to create the laguage model are [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=52496278389722227912) . Im using cygwin on windows 8.1 to run SRILM 1.7.1. But once i run the command

```
ngram-count -vocab sinhalalexicon.txt -text sinhalacorpus.Train -order 3     -write sinhala.count -unk
```

I'm getting

```
iconv: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
iconv: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

What did I do wrong here? sinhalacorpus.Train file was created by manually using Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my issue. once I convert the corpus and lexicon files to **Unix format** and change the encoding to **UTF-8 without BOM** it worked. I used Notepad++ to do the changes.